# Gratis iOS application to track how much WiFi data I currently use

Tags: gratis, ios, monitoring, network-monitor, wifi

I'm looking a gratis iOS application that can track how much WiFi data I currently use.

---

I am aware of the the following applications, but they are not gratis:

- https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/system-status-pro-hw-monitor/id401457165
- https://apps.apple.com/us/app/dataman-data-usage-widget/id592962356

On Android I use [Network Speed - Internet Speed Meter - Indicator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evozi.network&hl=en_US&gl=US):

[image]

Comment: An alternative is to check the consumption of your data on your home router

Answer (score 0):

[Usage](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/usage-widgets/id970353453) provides something like that in its free version. If you want to customize over what period to count the data consumption (other than per day / per calendar month) you will have to pay the €4.99 for the full version however.